# Purge HTML but leave Line Breaks

Tags: templating

I'm looking to purge all the `html` from a text field, but leave the line breaks in there. I currently have the following code, which makes line breaks happen, but unfortunately, people can add `html` to the text field and it will render it.

```
    {{ user.userAbout|raw }}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the Twig [|striptags](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html) filter, which is a wrapper for PHP's [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)